# React to Property Change in a Collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection of object attached to my `$scope`. One of the properties is data-bound to a drop down control. When the drop down changes, I want to make an AJAX call and update some of the values of the active item when the response comes back.

I've tried using

```
$scope.$watch('items', function (_old, _new) {
  console.log('hit')
}, true);
```

and that kind of works. I see 'hit' being logged to the console when I change the drop down. Further reading seemed to indicate that this is the most inefficient watch method, especially if the number of items grows beyond the non-trivial size.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I dispatch an event or something when the data-bound property changes?

Answer (score 0):

This provides a great explaination of how each of $watch $watchCollection and $watch(comparor)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm

I would really recommend giving it a view.  Essentially you will want to watch the deep value using a comparor.

If performance becomes an issue you will simply want to flatten the data you are trying to watch or slice it up.